# Matching two columns from a database

Tags: mysql, url-rewriting, pattern-matching, url-routing

I'm gonna implement a new design / website structure for a customer, but I have a little problem. Since the URLs I've created are a bit different, I'm anticipating a problem with the SEO rankings due to the bunch of broken URLs. My idea is to match the existing URLs (from the old site) with the new ones I've created.

The problem I've stumbled upon is the following:

The **old URLs** are like `http://www.example.com/category/numeric_id-item-name_item_code.html` and the **new URLs** are like`http://www.example.com/item_name-item_code.`

In MySQL I created a new database containing on the first column the item_name and item_code from the old website and a second column the same info from the new database.

The idea is as it follows:
Example: Let's say we have an item named *spring leaf* with the code *sl34*. The old URL would be something like `http://www.example.com/springs/53-spring-leaf-sl34.html`. 
For matching this URL there are 3 possibilities:

1. If the product is in the new website `http://www.example.com/spring-leaf-sl34`
2. In case they modified the name `http://www.example.com/iron-spring-leaf-sl34`
3. In case the product is not in the new website: `http://www.example.com/springs`

I need help on creating these matches.

Thank you.

Comment: if item code and product name are both alpha numeric then how do you distinguish which is which?

Comment: Hmmm... you might have given me an ideea... the only thing that's steady in that example is the product code... So, I guess I could match the product codes and keeping that as a criteria i could make a table like "Matching_id   Old_URL   New_URL".

Comment: In case this does not work out, it is possible to check the URL at code level (using PHP+database) and issue a 301 redirect from the code... something that stackoverflow does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently, I've found some kind of quick fix:

```
CREATE
   VIEW `database`.`url_view` 
    AS
(SELECT old_table.old_url, new_table.new_url FROM old_table LEFT JOIN new_table ON old_table.product_code=new_table.product_code);
```

This will associate the old URLs with the new ones, and, if an old URL (product) is no longer available it will insert a (NULL) entry.